# GoodMap API3 with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I work on application in which i need map i worked in map module and in browser it shows correct result but as it is an mobile application so i run it into emulator and the following error occues

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function at file:///android_asset/www/nav-map.html:3
```

my html file `Nav-map.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css">
    <script src="js/hsmain.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <link href="css/mobiscroll.custom-2.5.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="photoswipe/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoswipe/klass.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="photoswipe/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jqm-datebox.min.css" /> 
    <script src="js/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.datebox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js"></script> 




    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/work-space.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/config.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/userprofile.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/loginlogout.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/binder.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/newsfeed.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/harvestdata.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/members.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/pictures.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/properties.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/clubnewsfeeds.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jsutility.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/weather.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/groups.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/groupnewsfeeds.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/companies.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/companynewsfeeds.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/map.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/searching.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/notitfications.js"></script>

    <link href="960/jquery-mobile-fluid960.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        #map-canvas
        {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="ClubMapPage">
        <!--header-->
<script>$('#ClubMapPage').on('pageshow',function(){
UserProfile.loadProfile();
Notifications.getTopNotification();
                Properties.getClubNameAndImage();
                Map.getMap();
            })
        </script>

        <div id="landing-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div class="container_12 padding5">
                <div class="grid_1">
                    <span class="inline-button floatleft"><a href="harvest-properties.html" onClick="Properties.getListOfFriendProperty()" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="back-btn"  data-theme="a">Back</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_10">
                    <div class="hs-icon-wrap">
                        <span class="dropdown inline-button"><a class="hs-request dropdown-toggle showRequestsBtn" data-toggle="dropdown" data-role="button" href="#messages" data-iconpos="notext" >Requests</a>
                        </span>             
                        <span class="dropdown inline-button"><a class="hs-notification dropdown-toggle showNotificationsBtn" data-role="button" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-iconpos="notext" >Notifications</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_1">
                    <span class="inline-button floatright"><a href="#right-panel" class="hs-menu-btn hsr">Right</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--contents-->
        <div data-role="content" class="hs-content">
        <div class="hs-notifications-menu-contents-wrap feeds-content-header HSnotifications">
                <div class="hs-notification-menu-heading">
                    Notifications
                    <a title="Remove" class="removebutton hideNotificationsBtn" href="javascript://" >Remove  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="hs-notifications-menu-items-wrap" >
                    <ul class="hs-notificatin-list notificationul">

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="hs-notification-menu-footer">
                    <a class="seemore" href="#" title="">
                        <span>See All</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Of Notifications -->
            <div class=" hs-notifications-menu-contents-wrap feeds-content-header HSrequests" >
            <div class="hs-notification-menu-heading">
                Requests
                <a title="Remove" class="removebutton hideRequestsBtn" href="#"  >Remove  </a>
            </div>
            <div class="hs-notifications-menu-items-wrap" style="">
                <ul class="hs-notificatin-list requestul">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="hs-notification-menu-footer">
                <a class="seemore" href="#" title="">
                    <span>See All</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of requests -->
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="content-header">
                    <h4><a href="property-activity-feeds.html" onClick="Properties.fullDetailOfClub()"  title="" class="clubNameOnTop"><img class="smallClubImage" alt="" src="images/header-small-image.png" /></a></h4>
                    <a href="basic-info.html" onClick="Properties.getClubBasicInfo(Properties.currentClubId())" class="info-link" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext">Info</a>        
                    <div data-role="navbar" class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="c">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="no-border"><a href="members.html"  id="nav-member" data-icon="custom">Members</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="nav-map.html"  id="nav-map"  data-icon="custom">Map</a></li>
                            <li><a href="harvest.html" id="nav-harvest"  data-icon="custom">Harvest</a></li>
                            <li><a href="clubpages/albums.html" id="nav-picture"  data-icon="custom" >Picture</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>

                <div class="content-wrap map-wrap">
                    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0">
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
        </div>



    </div>
```

Comment: Hi i see your your JS file that you post i think i understand what the problem is but first something i want to know that the js files that you included are same as you posted i means same way to define them like

`var Map = {....`

Comment: @BluAngel yes almost all in same approach

Comment: i already see your map file i would know about what is the name in camera.js file? i think you put the class name on some JS keywords like Map is also the function / varible name in google map api

Comment: in camera js i initilize class with name `Image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is some problem with your class names you put the class names same as some keywords like `Image` you cannot put `Image` as a class name also check if other same problem exist i think you should check by using some IDE it will shows the special names in different color.
also change the class name `Map`
I had the same error once i think it will help you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but I solved it two months ago!
I was because a jquery plugin of mine was not ending in `;` 
You can Try to end your JS lines with  `;` I can see you don't follow this best practices advice. So, add it to you own js files (at the end) in order to let the files concatenation understand That a new file is really a new single function (or statement)

Sorry If this is not the solution to your problem! Thank you for reading

Comment: Thanks Ada for your attentions
but it didn't solve my problem